# How to extract console output into variable between two points?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I would like to extract the section of console output that occurs between two specific points in a program and store that into a variable. This would be executed in a loop many times. There is no need for output to be echoed into the regular console (if that makes things more efficient).

i.e.

```
foreach (Procedure p in procedures) {
    BeginCapturingConsoleOutput();

    p.Execute();

    string procedureOutput = EndCapturingConsoleOutput();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on this page in MSDN does what I think you are looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx

Basically, it sets the output stream to something that you define (in the case of the example, a file), performs some action, and at the end sets it back to the standard output stream.

Comment: Fantastic! That very easily can be implemented into what I need. I was looking around the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class which seems to offer similar functionality for spawned processes, but not the current process. `Console.SetOut` works like a charm :-)

Comment: Here is an example for future readers that might be interested: http://pastebin.com/s10fZ0XE